# How to clear the content of editable UIWebview without dismissing the keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `UIWebView` with the content editable set to true. Now if tap on the `UIWebView` a cursor appears on the `UIWebView` and the keyboard pops up. Now I am able to write some thing in this editable `UIWebView`.

My problem is that when I try to clear the content of this editable `UIWebView`, the content gets cleared but the keyboard is also gets dismissed. I want to clear the content of the editable `UIWebView` without dismissing the keyboard.

I am using following code to clear the editable UIWebView.

`[self.webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and clear the webview through javascript:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML = '';"];
```

Reloading the web view will set it into a default state where it is not currently being edited and the keyboard is hidden. With the above snippet, you are going to directly change the content of the web view without affecting its state.